# Python kivy open gl error

Tags: python, opengl, kivy

I just installed kivy 1.9.1 with python 3.4 on Windows 7. I also have upgraded the video drivers to the latest one and tried to run the sample application:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')
```

but I got error that my OpenGL is not up-to-date. The log is uploaded in the image:

[image]

Comment: Just a blind guess, but try restarting the machine.

Comment: I tried but still wont work.I also tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969990/kivy-does-not-detect-opengl-2-0