# Is there a way to draw a smooth RoundedRectangle in Kivy?

Tags: windows, opengl, kivy

When I use the `RoundedRectangle` in Kivy, the rounded corners are **jaggy (not smooth)**.

Is it possible to create a smooth rounded button (with transparent corners)?

Here is my test code:

```py
import os
os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'angle_sdl2'
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout

class MyLayout(AnchorLayout):
    pass

Builder.load_string('''
<RoundedButton@Button>:
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (200, 50)
    background_color: 0,0,0,0  # alpha=0
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.4,.4,.4,1) if self.state=='normal' else (0,.7,.7,1)  # visual feedback of press
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            radius: [self.size[1]//2]

<MyLayout>
    anchor_x: 'center'
    anchor_y: 'center'
    RoundedButton:
        text: 'Rounded Button'
''')

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

TestApp().run()
```

Note: because the configuration `os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'angle_sdl2'` you might need Windows OS with DirectX to reproduce this code exactly. See [Kivy issue #6276](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6276).

Comment: Are you building the app for android? It gets a way smoother when it is compiled and installed on your android phone than it looks when you start your application for example on windows. You can try your code in the kivy launcher application to get a first impression.

Comment: On Linux, after commenting out `os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = ...`, the button appears perfectly round on the left and right; see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1JGA.png).

Comment: I can also recommend KivyMD. They have a nice [variety of beautiful buttons](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/button/index.html). [MDFillRoundFlatButton](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/button/index.html#mdfillroundflatbutton) might be what you want.

Comment: @bitinerant, unfortunately your screenshot does not show soft rounded edges.  We can see a staircase pattern on the border, like old graphics from the 90's.

Comment: @MisterNox, no, I'm on Wondows 10.

Comment: @bitinerant, thanks for the KivyMD suggestion. It does not solve this problem, but offers really interresting widgets

Comment: Not reproducible on Linux. I got: `x11 - Exception: CGL: ANGLE backend can be used only on Windows`. Seems [for `angle_sdl2` you need to have _DirectX 11_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54806913/kivy-error-critical-app-unable-to-get-a-window-abort)