# What we have to do to run py files with kivy module

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

[image]

I have inserted a picture, In this it is showing error while running file of python by using 'kivy' module, can someone tell me what i have to do to run this 'kivy' file , is i need to change my graphic card or what I have to do someone tell

This is he file that I am trying to run

```
import kivy from kivy.app import App from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='hello')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to install OpenGl 2.0 or higher as it says. You can download the latest version [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/opengl-driver). This is just a graphics driver, software to interact with your gpu. If you use nvidia you can even automatically download any necessary drivers from their [Geforce Experience](https://www.nvidia.com/en-gb/geforce/geforce-experience/) program, but I'm not sure about AMD or integrated graphics.

However, if you already have version 2.0 or above and the error persists, try one of the answers found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34969990/14316282)